# Refactoring code inside of for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

In my application, I am using a for loop and an if-else statement in side of it.
The client is suggesting that we avoid loops, which means we need to avoid the conditional statements inside of the loop.

```
AbstractImporter importer = null;
for (UploadedFile uploadedFile : uploadedFiles) {
    if (StringUtils.contains(uploadedFile.getName(), "_" + locale)) {
        importer = "";
        ImporterFactory.getImporterForType(getExtension(uploadedFile.getName()));
        try {
            tableRows.addAll(importer.importData(uploadedFile));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
            FacesMessageUtil.addGlobalUnexpectedErrorMessage();
        }
    } else {
        FacesMessageUtil.addStatusMessage(TOP_PANEL, MESSAGEKEY, new Object[]{uploadedFile.getName()});
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `uploadedFiles` ? Is it a `List` ?

Comment: Lots of things _require_ loops. Why would your client suggest you avoid loops?

Comment: Where is the problem? `if`-`else` is no loop but a conditional. Therefore you only have one loop and no nested loops.

Comment: This code seems okay already, the loop is necessary for going through your uploadedFiles list.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy, please also correct the spelling of "Refactering" to "Refactoring".  I see the edit button disabled for me.

Comment: So I formatted the code and fixed the grammar, but boy am I confused by that `importer = ""` statement.  You had backticks there but I really, really doubt that's what you meant, and doubt even *more* that it would compile that way.  If you can't use the exact code example, could you at least initialize that variable to something usable?

Comment: >"The client is suggesting that we avoid loops" LOLWUT

Comment: Maybe the client heard that INFINITE LOOPS ARE BAD somewhere (or had a horrible experience with loops), thus now fearing all loops?

Comment: Unless your collection is insanely large (on the order of tens of thousands of elements), then there's really no point in getting rid of the loop or making it more efficient.  What scale are you talking about?  Also, it would be better to have a minimally compiling example so that those who wish to rid you of your loop problem could do so slightly easier.

Comment: This sounds like the client wants a responsive program and instead of refactoring the client needs threads. But this is not meta-consulting, so good software requires good requirements too.